# Goggle Apps Script integration with Zabbix

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, zabbix, google-apps-script-api, zabbix-api

I made an item in zabbix that runs a local PS1 file on the host machine

[This is the item, when I access the specific Host and use the execute now function it works perfectly and runs the ps1 file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lwxl.png)

I needed to make Apps Script carry out this process of executing the item on a specific host (I would pass the host to the code and it to Zabbix).

is it possible to do that?

I created a zabbix API token and tried to run this item but without success, I didn't find any video or documentation that does something similar